# Is there a limit to how many lines can go into a single css command?

Tags: css

Okay, so I'm trying to do my homework for school, and I'm finally starting to work on CSS.

My issue is that the code I enter, for id `#articleheader` does not apply, and the only reason I can think of is that there are four rules present before I close the line.

```css
#articleheader {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 7px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header id="articleheader">
  <h1>Bike the Mountains Tour</h1>
</header>
```

Any help?

Comment: There probably is some theoretical limit, but 4 properties is nowhere near it. Your CSS works fine for me. Are you using an external stylesheet? If so, is it linked to your HTML document? Are you overriding the h1 styles somewhere else?

Comment: As you can see in the demo above.. it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `h1` has its own styles for size and weight, even by default if you don't set them specifically.  To set them for the `h1`:

```
#articleheader h1 {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems fine in terms of what you are trying to do and when your code is dropped into a html document. If the solution offered by Matt still isn't working I suggest you need to check that you have the css file linked to properly if an external stylesheet or it's onpage make sure you have it wrapped around  tags properly.

```
<html>

<head>
<style>
#articleheader {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: normal;
        letter-spacing: 7px;
        text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body
    <header id="articleheader">
     <h1>Bike the Mountains Tour</h1>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`You should apply the id="articleheader" tag with h1,not with header.
**Although,there is nothing wrong with using id tag in header, the results will not be as expected.** i.e. the properties would be applied,but at a different scale.

[This is the result when id is applied on h1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa6ZL.png)

[This is the result when id is applied on header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdyKt.png)

```
<header>
     <h1 id="articleheader">Bike the Mountains Tour</h1>
</header>
```

There is nothing wrong with the css code

The precedence of id tag being applied on h1 is proved when same id tag is applied on both h1 and header, but results as shown in the earlier image(h1 with id) are displayed.

```
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
     <header id="articleheader" >
        <h1 id="articleheader" >Bike the Mountains Tour</h1>
     </header>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I was going from what was written in my textbook: "You need to name different elements within the document using the id attribute. Add the following ids to the document: a) name the first header element pageheader and the second header element articleheader; and b) name the first section element leftsection and the second section element rightsection."